# How to sort the list by its accountID using quick sort in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, functional-programming

Im a student who is really new to functional programming. Im working on a banking application where the data has been already defined as,

```
type Accountno = Int 
data Accounttype = Saving | Current  | FixedDeposit deriving (Show,Read)
type Accountamount = Int
type Name = String 
type Account = (Accountno, Name, Accounttype, Accountamount) 


exampleBase :: [Account]
exampleBase = [ (1,"Jennifer",Saving,1000 ) , 
    (5,"Melissa",Current,3000) ,
    (2,"Alex",Saving,1500)]
```

Im trying to sort the list by its account number using the following code,

```
sortByID :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sortByID [] = []
sortByID (l :ls) =
  let
   smallerSorted = sortByID [x | x <- ls, x <= l]
   biggerSorted = sortByID [x | x <- ls, x > l]
  in
   smallerSorted ++ [l] ++ biggerSorted


viewSortedDetails :: IO()
viewSortedDetails = 
    do
     putStrLn "Account Details Sorted By Account ID"
     let records = sortByID exampleBase
     let viewRecord = map show records
     mapM_ putStrLn viewRecord
```

But I do not get the expected result. as it gives me an error, informing "Instance of Ord Accounttype required for definition of viewSortedDetails".Please can some one help me to overcome this problem
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you're using ordering comparisons, such as `<=`, on two `Account` values, which would require `Account` to be an instance of `Ord`. Now, `Account` is a synonym for a four-element tuple, which are defined to be instances of `Ord` when all the types in the tuple are. `Accountno`, `Name`, and `Accountamount` are all synonyms for types with `Ord` instances, but `Accounttype` is not.

You could make it possible to sort `Account` values directly by making `Accounttype` an instance of `Ord`, which you can do by simply adding it to the `deriving` clause.

However, if you want to specifically sort *only* by the account number, not the other elements of the tuple, you'll need to do something differently. One option would be to make `Account` a data type with a custom `Ord` instance:

```
data Account = Account Accountno Name Accounttype Accountamount deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Ord Account where
    (...)
```

Then you can define the ordering however you like.

Alternatively, you can leave it as is and instead only compare the element you want instead of the entire `Account` value, using something like this:

```
accountNo :: Account -> Accountno
accountNo (n,_,_,_) = n
```

...and then doing the comparison with something like `smallerSorted = sortByID [x | x <- ls, accountNo x <= accountNo l]`. The standard libraries also include a function `on` for this purpose, but it would awkward to use in this case.

---

A few other remarks, which are less relevant to your question, on the general subject of Haskell code:

- Defining `Account` as a data type, probably using the record syntax, would be nicer than using a type synonym here. Large tuples can be awkward to work with.
- `Accountno` and `Accountamount` should probably be different types as well, to avoid mixing them with other `Int`s: the first because doing arithmetic on account numbers makes little sense, the latter in part because (I'm guessing) you're implicitly using fixed point arithmetic, such that 100 actually means 1.00, and in general just to avoid confusion.
- In fact, `Int` is probably a bad choice for `Accountamount` anyway: Why not something from `Data.Fixed`, `Ratio Integer`, or a base-10-safe floating point type (although there isn't one in the standard libraries, unfortunately).
- The standard libraries of course include sorting functions already--I'm assuming the reimplementation is for learning purposes, but in practice it could all be replaced by something like `` sortBy (compare `on` accountNo) ``.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer. A lot appreciated. I tried out the second method u have mentioned. But still it gives me an error informing, Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : sortByID
*** Expected type : Ord a => [a] -> [a]
*** Inferred type : Ord (Int,[Char],Accounttype,Int) => [(Int,[Char],Accounttype,Int)] -> [(Int,[Char],Accounttype,Int)]  Can you be kind enough to help me with this. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @user421607: Extracting an element from the tuple puts more restrictions on the type being sorted: It requires a list of `Account`, not a generic list like `[a]`. If you just remove the type signature it should infer the correct one, but `[Account] -> [Account]` should be what it wants.

Comment: I tired out in that manner too...But still it gave me errors.I'l try out ur first method. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @user421607: Adding the `accountNo` function and removing the type signature on `sortByID` worked for me. Did you forget to add the `accountNo` function in one of the comparisons?

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked for me too :) . This was a huge help for the time being.

Comment: There is a fixed point float: in module Data.Fixed: data Fixed a, where "Fixed E2" is the fixed point Integer with two decimal digits after the dot. <http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Fixed.html>

Comment: @comonad: That's still fixed-precision, which wasn't quite what I had in mind--but I had forgotten about it all the same, and it'd make more sense than using `Ratio`, so thanks!

Comment: Er, awkward?  <code>sortByID = sortBy (compare \`on` accountNo)</code>.  Reads like English.

Comment: @luqui: Awkward to stick into the list comprehensions in his code as it stands. Not awkward at all when used your way, since that's exactly what it's meant for! I was trying not to suggest totally rearranging his code, since I don't know the point of the learning exercise. I did mention the definition using `sortBy` in my remarks at the end.

Comment: @luqui: Of course, the *really* awkward part is trying to use backtick infix notation in inline code snippets on Stack Overflow. Sigh.